# delete whitespace in regular expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python and also english. And I have a problem that might be easy, but I can't solve it. I have a folder of .txt's, I was able to extract by regular expression a sequence of 17 numbers of each one.I need to rename each file with the sequence I extracted from .txt

```
import os
import re

path_txt = (r'C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\files')


name_files = os.listdir(path_txt)


for TXT in name_files:
    with open(path_txt + '\\' + TXT, "r") as content:
        search = re.search(r'(\d{5}\.?\d{4}\.?\d{3}\.?\d{2}\.?\d{2}\-?\d)', content.read())
        if search is not None:
            print(search.group(0))
            f = open(os.path.join( "Processes" , search.group(0) + ".txt"), "w")
        for line in content:
            print(line)
            f.write(line)
            f.close()
```

there are .txt where the sequences appear with spaces between characters, and my regular expression can not find them (example: 00372.2004 .442.02.00-1, 00572.2008.872.02.00- 5)

edit: They are serial numbers, were typed, so sometimes they appear with "." and "-" and other times without them. Sometimes spaces appear because of typos.

Comment: Your regular expression only accepts digits `\d`, periods `\.` and a minus sign, so it is no wonder it doesn't accept a string with a white space in it.  A whitespace is written `\w`, or just as a regular space if you know that is what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this regex:

```
   search = re.search(r'(\d{5}.*\d{4}.*\d{3}.*\d{2}.*\d{2}-.*\d)', content.read())
```

Dot . is any character. By putting \ in front of the dot you escaped it and searched for dots and not any character.

Comment: Does it work when the sequences appear concatenated?

Comment: Yes. Because the * means any character can occur 0 until unlimited times...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\D` in your regular expression to match any non-numeric character (including white space) and `+` to match one or more (or `*` to match zero or more), so you could rewrite your expression as:

```
pattern = r'(\d{5}\D+\d{4}\D+\d{3}\D+\d{2}\D+\d{2}\D+\d)'
re.findall(pattern, '00372.2004 .442.02.00-1, 00572.2008.872.02.00- 5')
# ['00372.2004 .442.02.00-1', '00572.2008.872.02.00- 5']
```

Note I am using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to find every match in the string and return them in a list.